# Replace each and every string in PowerShell is not working as expected

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a loop for replacing the all the matching values.

```
Key                                                          Value                                                       
---                                                          -----                                                       
client                                                      xxxx                                                  
type                                                         Test                                                        
name                                                     xxx                                          
env                                                    ALL
```

and I have another app.config file, looks as follows,

```
    <add key="ClientName" value="{{client}}" />
    <add key="InstallForClients" value="{{client}}" />
```

I'm tring to match each and every string (which exits between two curly braces ) with each and every key in dictionary. if it is match, replace string with value.

I'm not able to replace the values. Here is the powershell script I'm working on,

```
if ("$string" -eq "$stringtocheck")
{
echo "Replacing $stringtocheck with $newstring in $source"
(Get-content $source) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '{{$stringtocheck}}', $newstring } | Set-Content $destination
}
}
```

Can someone please help me in updating this replacing loop.

Comment: not sure if this is the only issue, but right here: `-replace '{{$stringtocheck}}'` you should change the single quotes to double quotes if you want to use the value of your $stringtocheck variable

Comment: Even with double quotes, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$config = Get-Content 'C:\temp\configoriginal.txt'

$hash = @{
    '{client}' = '{Arizona}'
    '{type}' = '{Test}'
    '{servicename}' = '{DataGenerator}'
    '{filetype}' = '{ALL}'
}

foreach ($key in $hash.Keys) {
    $config = $config -replace [regex]::Escape($key), $hash[$key]
}

$config | Set-Content 'C:\temp\configchanged.txt'
```

Comment: Updated my script with this line,
    $config = $source -replace [regex]::Escape($stringtocheck), $myDictionary.GetEnumerator()
$config | Set-Content $destination

But I'm still not able to replace the values.

Comment: you said you updated your script. have you tried just using my script? try replacing c:\temp\configoriginal.txt with the path of your config file.

Comment: I have used this command. $config = $source -replace [regex]::Escape($stringtocheck), $myDictionary.GetEnumerator() $config | Set-Content $destination